# how to show all methods that i can choose in ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to `ipython` notebook. When typing a code line, it should show all methods or attributes that I can choose. However, it didn't, and I'm not sure why.

It should look like this:

[image: Example]

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: btw, TAB not work for me, i am using Mac OS, python 2.7, ipython 5.3 and notebook 5.0

Answer (score 30):

1. Type the library name
2. Type period symbol `.`
3. Press tab

At this point you will see drop down menu (showing all the methods)

[image]

This works for both python 2 and python 3

Answer (score 2):

That should be a new feature of IPython 6.0.

But as mentioned in [the official release post](http://blog.jupyter.org/2017/04/19/release-of-ipython-6-0/#highlightedfeaturejedicompletion), is still just for command line users, and they are working to port it to all other users.

Comment: i see...looks like i need to update my python as well, thanks a lot~