# How to show all methods possible in jupyter notebook in MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I found similar questions but none relate to my issue in **MacOS**

[Showing all possible methods on Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636383/showing-all-possible-methods-on-jupyter-notebook)

[how to show all methods that i can choose in ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795676/how-to-show-all-methods-that-i-can-choose-in-ipython-notebook)

Many people didn't find those answers useful in MacOS as you can see in the comments.

[image]

I'm trying to use `. + tab` to display all the possible methods any initialized object in Jupyter notebook like this:

(example image of a list object for context)

[image: example image of a list object for context]

and none will show up. But in memory variables can be shown.

I'm launching Jupyter Notebook from my MacOS terminal from a virtual environment with the following versions

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.1
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.5.0
```

How can I configure Jupyter Notebook in order to show all possible methods when I use `tab`?

---

**UPDATE**

- Upgraded to `notebook==6.0.1` and still doesn't work
- In the same environment, `ipython` **displays** methods when using `tab`
- `%config IPCompleter.greedy=True` was set and still doesn't work
- `pyreadline` installed still doesn't work
- it worked with lists but with a pandas empty data frame `df. + tab` wont display possible methods neither with an Axessubplot object.
- This issue was replicated in a linux distro and the notebook hangs in kernel busy by using one thread by 100% until it finally displays the possible methods. In MacOs it doesn't hang in 'kernel busy' and won't display anything only when you add a hint (like `df.h + tab` will show `head` and `hist`)

Comment: You have initialized `a`, right?

Comment: Yes, the object I'm 'tabing' is initialized already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this issue was discussed here [Autocomplete not working](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435)

You should downgrade your `ipython` version to `6.2.1`
by running in your virtual environment:

```
pip install ipython==6.2.1
```

and then restart the jupyter notebook. Now it should display the methods of any object including pandas and seaborn ones like this

[image]

Comment: `! jupyter notebook --version:  5.7.8` and it's not working by replicating your example with `time` library. I will try to downgrade my Jupyter notebook version and update my comment. Thanks

Comment: Downgraded to `5.7.4` with `tornado 4.2.0` and it didn't work neither

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia have you installed `readline`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665039/tab-completion-does-not-work-in-jupyter-notebook-but-fine-in-ipython-terminal

Comment: Yes. I have installed `pyreadline` and also added  `%config IPCompleter.greedy=True`
And still doesn't work

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia Did it work when you use `Ipython` in the terminal?

Comment: Now it works with lists but not with an empty dataframe of pandas or axesublplot of seaborn, neither in ipython nor jupyter

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5k6cv8/pythonjupyter_notebookhow_to_enable_autocomplete/

Comment: It worked with the first link, do you want to update your answer ? by downgrading ipython to version 6.2.1.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia Glad to hear that, you can edit my answer or you can give your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu Server running with Python3
```

Here what helped in my case:

## Infastructure update

1. I had fresh install, so update pip3 package

   python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
2. See if there are any outdated packages

   python3 -m pip list --outdated --format=freeze
3. If there are any (which is highly possible) use this to update everything

   python3 -m pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 python3 -m pip install -U
4. In my case I've also installed python3-cairo-dev

### Core programming rules

Also it is important to remember, that you better have item defined first. Like

```
myAwesomeList = []
myAwesomeList.<- here we press "Tab"
```